# Android: icon drawable padding

Tags: android, imageview

I created icon resource on Android Asset Studio with no padding. The icon has a blank on the left and right side. When I set it as a source in ImageView, the ImageView looks like having padding on left and right.

How can I remove the blank on the left and right of the icon in the ImageView?

Here is my icon:
[image]

Comment: can u post the icon and xml as well ?

Comment: Just try to set image in background property if you are using src property.

Comment: I've updated my icon in the question.

Answer (score 0):

i think your image may be small size.In these case  your  imageview add the property  scaleType as centerCrop.

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

The dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

for more details refer [ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the Xml file

android:scaleType="centerCrop"